# How to prepend only those lines with tabs/spaces in a file, with esc character?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk, sed

Description: The entire line that contains either tab/tabs and/ or space/spaces followed by new line character and no other character needs to be escaped.  There are several such lines scattered in a huge file of data.

To be noted:
Here by space I mean either ( tabs or spaces ) only not blank lines.
The blank lines that only has a new line character should not be prepended (needs to be removed). This removal part may or may not be implemented in the one-liner.

Basically would like to know if possible by using sed/perl/awk one-liners.

Thanks in advance.

My attempt were these without much success...

Tried these without much success..

```
sed -i 's/\^[\s\+\|\t\+]\+\$\n/\^\\[\s\+\|\t\+]\+\$\n/g' filename

perl -i -ne 'chomp; print \"\\\$_\n\" if (\$_ eq \"\")' filename

perl -pi -ne 's/\S\+/\\\S\+/g if (\$_ eq \"\")' filename

sed -i 's/\^[:space:]\+\$\n/\^\\[:space:]\+\$\n/g' filename
```

Comment: Tried these without much success..  
sed -i 's/\^[\s\+\|\t\+]\+\$\n/\^\\[\s\+\|\t\+]\+\$\n/g' filename

perl -i -ne 'chomp; print \"\\\$_\n\" if (\$_ eq \"\")' filename

perl -pi -ne 's/\S\+/\\\\\S\+/g if (\$_ eq \"\")' filename

sed -i 's/\^[:space:]\+\$\n/\^\\[:space:]\+\$\n/g' filename

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with "... needs to be escaped". Could you edit your post to include some sample input and sample output?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Some one-liners contain 10,000+ characters and are completely unreadable - since you asked for a "one-liner" that may be what you get, hope that's OK.

Comment: By needs to be escaped I mean those line should remain in file, but prepended with an esc character "\". Those line should not be removed from file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -i.bak -nle 's~^(\s++)$~\\$1~; /\S/ and print' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks seems more appropriate for my purpose

Answer (score 1):

To prepend lines that only contain whitespace with a backslash you can do :

```
awk 'NF==0 && length($0){$0="\\" $0}1' file
```

To also remove blank lines, you can do:

```
awk 'NF==0 && length($0){$0="\\" $0}length($0)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to use the posix character classes:

```
sed -r 's/^([[:space:]]+)$/\\\1/;/^$/d' yourfile
```

This preserves the spaces in your lines containing spaces, just prepending the backslash. Note that instead of `[:space:]` you could also use `[:blank:]`, with the former matching all whitespace characters (equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`), while the latter matches only strictly spaces and tabs (equivalent to `[ \t]`).

**EDIT**: I have also added the command to remove lines that are totally empty (after the semicolon in the **sed** command).

Comment: `[[:space:]]` can be an overkill. Mine: `sed -e 's|[[:blank:]]\+|\\&|; /^$/d' file`

Comment: Thanks Jaybee, but with sed the issue I am getting while using your oneliners or the ones i posted are

"sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command"


In one of the posts here in stackoverflow it suggests .....
script contains newlines in patterns. So it complains about the first line....
better off using perl's regular expressions to deal with multiline substitutions

Comment: Yeah, I also wanted to use the `$` in my replacement string, but for some strange reason I failed to use it correctly. +1!

Comment: @Seeker, are you sure you use double brackets around e.g. `:space:`? Also, that can be an issue about the use of the `+` metacharacter, which is part of the extended regexps (indicated by the `-r` flag we can give **sed**) but not of the standard regexps...

Comment: @Jaybee, yes i used double, earlier one bracket surrounding :space:, both way it gives the same issue.

Comment: FYI, it works with escaping \$, in the sense not getting any syntax issue, however, the required lines are not being prepended by "\". sed -ir 's/\^([[:space:]]\+)\$/\\\\1/;/\^\$/d' file –